# Query using 3 tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables with the following information

```
T_Loan
(
    PKLoan int not null primary key
    FK_Terminal int not null//Foreign key of T_Terminal
)

T_Terminal
(
    PK_Terminal int not null primary key
    Name_Terminal Varchar(200) not null
    FK_accessory int//Foreign key of T_Accesory
)

T_accessory 
(
    PK_accessory int not null primary key,
    accessory_name VARCHAR(200)
)
```

I would like a query that has `PKLoan`, `Name_Terminal` and `accessory_name`.

I am doing the following query to obtain the above:

```
Select 
    PKLoan, Name_Terminal, accessory_name
From 
    T_Loan l, T_Terminal t, T_accessory a
Where 
    l.FK_Terminal = t.PK_Terminal 
    and l.FKaccessory = a.PK_accessory
```

When I query the above it just shows me the ones with accessories, but it is not necessary that all of the terminals have accessories, I was told to search about Joins but I am not quite sure how to use them with 3 tables

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: It is irrespoinsible to use implict joins. THey area a SQL antipattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Right or Left Outer join` to get all the rows of `right or left table`. In your case you need have all the rows from T_Terminal even if they dont have accessories so `right join` the `T_Terminal` with `T_accessory`

```
SELECT *
FROM   T_accessory TC
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN T_Terminal TT
                     ON tc.PK_accessory = TT.FK_accessory
       JOIN T_Loan Tl
         ON tl.FK_Terminal = TT.PK_Terminal
```